# How to implement knn based on weights

Tags: r, knn, training-data, caret, weighted

I would like to implement the weighted knn algorithm but I don't know how to do it. Everything and that I can use kknn, I suppose that it can also be done with knn. In the function train(caret) there is an option "weights" but I can't find the solution, any suggestion?

I use the following code in R :

```
library(caret)
library(corrplot)
glass <- read.csv("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/glass/glass.data",
                  col.names=c("","RI","Na","Mg","Al","Si","K","Ca","Ba","Fe","Type"))
str(glass)

head(glass)

glass_1<- glass[,-7]
glass_2<- glass_1[,-7]
head(glass_2)
glass<- glass_2
standard.features <- scale(glass[,2:8])

data <- cbind(standard.features,glass[9])
anyNA(data)
head(data)
corrplot(cor(data))
data$Type<-factor(data$Type)
inTraining <- createDataPartition(data$Type, p = .7, list = FALSE, times =1 )
training <- data[ inTraining,]
testing  <- data[-inTraining,]
prop.table(table(training$Type))  
prop.table(table(testing$Type))
dim(training); dim(testing);
summary(data)

fitControl <- trainControl(## 5-fold CV
  method = "cv",
  number = 5,
  ## repeated ten times
  #repeats = 5)
)

#k_value <- expand.grid(kmax = 3, distance = 2, kernel = "optimal")
k_value <- expand.grid(k = 3)

set.seed(825)
knn_Fit <- train(Type ~ ., data = training, weights = ????,
                 method = "knn", tuneGrid = k_value, 
                 trControl = fitControl)
## This last option is actually one
## for gbm() that passes through
#verbose = FALSE)
knn_Fit
knn_Fit$finalModel
```

Comment: I can't understand the text in your question - "Everything and that I can use kknn"? Is it missing some words? It sounds like you're aware of the `kknn` package for weighted knn. Is the problem that you want to use it via `caret` rather than run it standalone? Maybe edit the question to make it clearer?

Comment: Sorry. I want to use only knn with weights, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: More details. I want to use knn (caret.) and I don't know how to apply, calculate or indicate the weights in the algorithm. is it possible?